# How to chain a Promise 'then' with 'all'

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm currently testing Promises and I'm working with the MDN example

```
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "one"); 
}); 
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, "two"); 
});
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000, "three");
});
var p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 4000, "four");
});
var p5 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject("reject");
});

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]).then(value => { 
  console.log(value);
}, reason => {
  console.log(reason)
});
```

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to call first the p1 function and then, when resolved that, call the Promise.all with p2, p3, p4, p5.

Thanks

Comment: `p1` is not a function, it's a promise. You already called `setTimeout` when you did create the promise, there's no way to change that.

Comment: does `p1.then(Promise.all([p2,p3,p4,p5])).then(v=>console.log(v),r=>console.log(r))` not work for you? I just literally wrote what you "said" you wanted and it should work as advertised.

Comment: @slebetman don't forget to wrap the `Promise.all` invocation in a callback function

Comment: @Bergi: No need. Then can accept a promise as well which is what `Promise.all` returns

Comment: @slebetman I've already tried but if I call reject on p1, p2 is called. I wanted to continue only if p1 resolve successffully

Comment: @slebetman: No, `then` does **not** accept promises as its argument. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @Bergi: From testing and using promises and from the spec (I checked just after posting the comment). We all know that callbacks in `then` can return a promise in order to be re-chainable right? Well, it turns out that if the object passed to `then` is not callable then it will be passed via the "Identity" function which is defined as `function (obj) {return obj}` so passing in a promise it is the same as calling a callback that returns a promise. See: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.prototype.then

Comment: @slebetman: Try and read again. Any non-function argument is *ignored* ([§25.4.5.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen) steps 3 and 4). The identity function returns the fulfillment value of the receiver promise, not of the `then` argument.

Comment: @Bergi: It's not ignored. 25.4.3.1 states that if the argument to then is not callable (not a function) then it is passed to the promisePerformThen by wrapping it with an identity function, if it is callable then is is passed as is. Then in 25.4.2.1 the spec defines what happens to values passed as Identity: they're treated as if the callback returns them (`let handlerResult be NormalCompletion(argument)`) - so if you pass a promise it will be treated as if you created and returned a promise in a callback.

Comment: @slebetman: No, nothing is "wrapped". The identity function itself is passed *instead* of the arrgument - `onFulfilled` is overwritten. In the `PromiseReactionJob`, the `argument` is the resolution value not the `then` argument. Seriously, why don't you stop arguing and just try `Promise.resolve(1).then(Promise.resolve(2)).then(console.log)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you're not using them right. `new Promise` starts its argument function immediately, so if you want to have control on when to *start* a Promise, you should keep functions returning Promises rather than raw Promise objects.

```js
w = console.log.bind(console);

var p1 = () => new Promise(r => {
   w('start p1');
   setTimeout(() => r(w('end p1')), 1000)
});

var p2 = () => new Promise(r => {
   w('start p2');
   setTimeout(() => r(w('end p2')), 200)
});

var p3 = () => new Promise(r => {
   w('start p3');
   setTimeout(() => r(w('end p3')), 3000)
});

var p4 = () => new Promise(r => {
   w('start p4');
   setTimeout(() => r(w('end p4')), 40)
});


p1()
  .then(() => Promise.all([p2(), p3(), p4()]))
  .then(() => w('all done'))
```

This waits for `p1` to complete and then executes `p2..4` simultaneously.

Comment: ohh perfect. I've tried to create new promises on return but I wasn't creating the Promise all on return. Thnanks

Answer (score -1):

You might do as follows if you would like to chain up all the promises.

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "one"); 
}); 
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, "two"); 
});
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000, "three");
});
var p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 4000, "four");
});
var p5 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject("reject");
});

var proms = [p1,p2,p3,p4,p5],
   result = proms.reduce((pp,cp) => pp.then(v => { console.log(v);
                                                   return cp;
                                                 }))
                 .then( v => console.log(v))
                 .catch(e => console.log("error at: ",e));
```